# After I populate my Spinner from an asynch API call, whatever item I choose from my Spinner, I get the first one

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I make a call using retrofit and RxJava to my API from my first fragment, then I display the respond I get in a Spinner. But whenever I select an item from my Spinner and click on the sendButton of my first fragment to send it to a second fragment I always receive the first item of my Spinner.

This is the code of my fragment

```
class SkillUpFragment : Fragment() {
    val TAG = SkillUpFragment::class.simpleName

    lateinit var skillsSpin : Spinner
    lateinit var model : SharedViewModel
    private val myCompositeDisposable= CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.skill_up_fragment, container, false)

        skillsSpin = view!!.findViewById(R.id.skill_spinner)
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)

        return view
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        loadData()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        myCompositeDisposable.dispose()
    }

    private fun loadData(){
        val token = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(activity!!.applicationContext).loginResponse.token
        val parsedJWT = JWT(token!!)
        val metaId = parsedJWT.getClaim("id")
        val id = metaId.asInt()

        myCompositeDisposable.add(RetrofitClient.instance.getSkillsToChoose(Id(id!!))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleResponse))

    }

    private fun handleResponse(skills: List<Skill>){
        val skillsName = skills.map { it.name }

        skillsSpin.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,skillsName)
        skillsSpin.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val skill = skillsName[id.toInt()]
                //When i display the value of skill before the button listener i get the right value
                Log.i(TAG, skill)
                frag_button_choose.setOnClickListener {
                    //whenever i click on the button, no matter what item i select i only from the spinner, i get always the first !!!
                    Log.i(TAG, skill)
                    model.setText(skill)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please this is very confusing, i've been stuck for more than a week, any help is welcome.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Select position not ID inside `onItemSelected`

```
 override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            val skill = skillsName[position]
            //When i display the value of skill before the button listener i get the right value
            Log.i(TAG, skill)
            frag_button_choose.setOnClickListener {
                //whenever i click on the button, no matter what item i select i only from the spinner, i get always the first !!!
                Log.i(TAG, skill)
                model.setText(skill)
            }
        }
```

That is all

Comment: know, sorry i should've changed that before uploading, i was just testing if it would work, but even position doesn't work!! And plus i don't know why but my items tend to ovelap when i choose one!! anyway thank you for you response :)

Comment: found the solution "skill" should be declared as a var!!